# Threadsafety and foreach with static readonly arrays

Tags: c#, foreach, static, thread-safety, readonly

I have got several arrays of type char[] and string[] that defined as 'static readonly'. Their items never change.

Are 'foreach' and 'generics' enumerations a threadsafe?

```
private static readonly string[] staticReadOnlyArray = new string[] { "someKey0", "someKey1", "someKey2", ... };

public bool SomeThreadSharedCall(string toCheck)
{
    // #1
    foreach (string s in staticReadOnlyArray)
    {
        if (s == toCheck)
            return true;
    }
    return false;

    // #2
    return staticReadOnlyArray.Contains(toCheck);

    // or #3
    return staticReadOnlyArray.Any(s => string.Compare(toCheck, s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);

    // or #4
    staticReadOnlyArray.ForEach(s => someAction(s, toCheck));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operations in your method are "threadsafe" only based on your claim that `Their items never change.`; however, nothing in the given code guarantees that.

The term [threadsafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) is normally used to mean that the code in question **guarantees** that the data will not change, or that if it *can* change, the operation will still produce the correct results.

You would need to perform [your own synchronization logic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679037.aspx) to make the code truly threadsafe.

=== Answer to your comments:

The return value of [GetEnumerator()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) -- what you're calling `iterator` -- is itself safe for exclusive use by the calling thread, but that's not the issue here. It's the underlying collection (the array) which is not thread safe, because it can change.

Changing the `foreach` to a `for` loop doesn't make the code any more thread safe. You need to either synchronize access to the collection, or make it immutable.

In your case, I suggest the latter given that the data in your array is constant. To make it concrete for you, here is some conceptual code:

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<string> staticReadOnlyData = Array.AsReadOnly( new string[] { "someKey0", "someKey1", "someKey2", ... } );

public bool SomeThreadSharedCall(string toCheck)
{
    // #1
    foreach (string s in staticReadOnlyData)
    {
        if (s == toCheck)
            return true;
    }
    return false;

    // #2
    return staticReadOnlyData.Contains(toCheck);

    // or #3
    return staticReadOnlyData.Any(s => string.Compare(toCheck, s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I clearly understand Win32 API multithreading on C++. But I confused with C# 4. The array is IEnumerable. For the move it uses a reference of IEnumerator<T> iterator = array.GetEnumerator().
So, is iterator referencing to the new copy of IEnumerator<T>, or each thread gets a reference to the one copy of iterator object? In the last case we have got a problem.

Comment: All I need - it's a constant predefined array and the thread-safe method for a lookup. I have a dilemma - to rewrite code from `foreach` to `for(int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Best way, if you're not sure, is to test it!  But yes, they are thread safe.